# PCRE: DEFINE statement for lookarounds

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Stepping deeper into the world of regular expressions, I came across the `DEFINE` Statement in `PCRE`.
I have the following code (which defines a lowercase, an uppercase and `anA` group (I know it's rather useless at this point, thanks :):

```
(?(DEFINE)
 (?<lowercase>(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])) # lowercase
 (?<uppercase>(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])) # uppercase
 (?<anA>A(?=B))
)
^(?&anA)
```

Now, I wonder how I can combine the lookahead (`lowercase` in this example) with the `anA` part? Admittedly, struggled to find an appropriate documentation on the `DEFINE` Syntax. Here's [a regex101.com fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/iD0qM5/1).
To make it somewhat clearer, I'd like to have the opportunity to combine subroutines. For instance, with the above example (to i.e. validate a password which needs to have an `A` followed by `B` and some lowercase letters), I could [do the following](https://regex101.com/r/iD0qM5/2):

```
^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z]).*?A(?=B).*
```

How can this be done with the above subroutines?

**EDIT:** For reference, I ended up using the [following construct](https://regex101.com/r/yL1cS5/4):

```
(?(DEFINE)
 (?<lc>(?=[^a-z\n]*[a-z]))      # lowercase
 (?<uc>(?=[^A-Z\n]*[A-Z]))      # uppercase
 (?<digit>(?=[^\d\n]*\d))       # digit
 (?<special>(?=.*[!@]+))        # special character
)
^(?&lc)(?&uc)(?&digit)(?&special).{6,}$
```

Comment: Jan, could you please clarify *how I can combine the lookahead (`lowercase` in this example) with the `anA` part* part? What do you want to match in your input string?

Comment: You didn't use x-flag for comment mode in your demo (matching a newline before `^` start of line). Maybe this confuses your expectations. Rexegg has some chapter about [predefined subroutes](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#define). Or in [pcre docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It is a) for a learning purpose and b) for a Password validation. I know I can write the lookaheads on their own, however I'd like to have it Kind of block-wise. I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Just recurse the subpattern as you have already done with `anA`: https://regex101.com/r/yL1cS5/1

Comment: Or [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yL1cS5/2).

Comment: There is just one caveat: *All  subroutine  calls, whether recursive or not, are always treated as **atomic groups**. That is, once a subroutine has matched some of the  subject string, it is never re-entered, even if it contains untried alternatives and there is  a  subsequent  matching  failure.  Any  capturing parentheses  that  are  set  during the subroutine call revert to their  previous values afterwards.*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks a lot, wanna turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How I can combine the lookahead (`lowercase` in this example) with the `anA` part

You can recurse the subpattern the same way as you have done it with `anA` by using the `(?&lowercase)` named subroutine call:

```
/(?(DEFINE)
   (?<lowercase>(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])) # lowercase
   (?<uppercase>(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])) # uppercase
   (?<anA>A(?=B))
  )
  ^(?&lowercase)(.*?)((?&anA)).*
/mgx
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ThEdHf/1). Note that you need to specify the VERBOSE/IgnorePatternWhitespace/Freespace mode with `/x` modifier at regex101.com for this pattern to work.

Beware of a caveat though in case you want to also DEFINE the `.*` and `.*?` subpatterns (see [PCRE Man Pages](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt)):

> **All subroutine calls, whether recursive or not, are always treated as atomic groups**. That is, once a subroutine has matched some of the subject string, it is never re-entered, even if it contains untried alternatives and there is a subsequent matching failure. Any capturing parentheses that are set during the subroutine call revert to their previous values afterwards.

Comment: Thanks again, Wiktor (link is broken).